# Read the String inside a ZipEntry: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a servlet that accepts ZIP files that contains XML files. I would like to read the content of those xml files but I am getting a java.io.IOException: Stream closed.

**I get the ZIP like this:**

```
private byte[] getZipFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    byte[] body = new byte[request.getContentLength()];
    new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream()).readFully(body);
    return body;
}
```

**And I read it like this:**

```
public static void readZip(byte[] zip) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);

    ZipEntry entry;

    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Entry: %s len %d", entry.getName(), entry.getSize()));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    zis.close();
}
```

**The output:**

```
Entry: file.xml len 3459
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
correct content of my xml file
</test>
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:67)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:116)
    at util.ZipHelper.readZip(ZipHelper.java:26)
```

**My question**

Why am I getting this exeption on this line ?

```
while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are wrapping your `zis` with `BufferedReader` so when you close `br`,`zis` will also close.

So remove `br.close` iteration will proceed without any exception.

Comment: That was it. Should I take the declaration out of the loop and close it afterwards ? Is there a better way of doing this ?